# Is it possible to pass java.io.FIle to JUnitCore.runClasses()

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to use JUnitCore.runClasses() and I can get it running using the following code

```
JUnitCore.runClasses(testClass.class);
```

But i was curious, as runClasses() can take any number of parameters, is it possible to use code similar to the following?

```
Class c = testClass.class;
JUnitCore.runClasses(c);
```

Or

```
List<Class> c = new ArrayList<>{test1.class, test2.class, test3.class};
JUnitCore.runClasses(c);
```

I am asking this as if you try to pass a java.io.File type to JUnitCore.runClasses() you get the following error

```
no suitable method found for runClasses(java.io.File)
method org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(java.lang.Class<?>...) is not applicable
  (argument type java.io.File does not conform to vararg element type java.lang.Class<?>)
method org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(org.junit.runner.Computer,java.lang.Class<?>...) is not applicable
  (actual argument java.io.File cannot be converted to org.junit.runner.Computer by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: How can you assign a Class instance to a variable of type File?  What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just coding off the top of my head here really... I was presuming you could set a file to be a .class file, can you not?

Comment: No, java.lang.Class is not assignable to java.io.File.

Comment: Yes, but when you try to pass it to the method, Java won't see it as a Class object. Just as a File that happens to have the extension .class

Comment: Is there a way to do this so?

Comment: Load the class file with a ClassLoader first, pass the resultant Class.

Comment: so i take it you can pass these classes loaded by the ClassLoader into a List<Class> then can you or do you have to pass the classes in one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to do the following:

You have a file containing a java class which you want to run using JUnitCore.

To acomplish this you will have to:

1. Load the class, this can be done by using a custom class loader. A better approach would be to just include the class into your application
2. Now you can invoke JUnitCore.runClasses(loadedClass);

**Code sample:**

```
File file = new File("path to your file");
File dir = file.getParentFile();
URL url = new URL("file://" + dir.getAbsolutePath());
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
Class<?> clazz = classLoader.findClass("ClassName");
JUnitCore.runClasses(clazz);
```

The example will only work if the class does not have a package. You can write an own class loader to control the class loading process. See the [javadoc for URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to learn how this class loader works. For writing a custom class loader you could consult [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/id1100.html).

Comment: yes that is exactly what i am trying to do... i will give this a go so

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a TestSuite class which contains all of the TestClass. And then you can call it by

```
JunitCore.runClasses(TestSuite.class);
```

TestSuite class contains the list of your TestClass such as

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    Test1.class,
    Test2.class
})
```